# php posgres website, but cannot insert data through form

Tags: php, postgresql, adminer

It is hard to find documentation on posgresql website for learning purpose and for some reason I cant insert data through submit form, please help, I thought my query is correct but it just didn't work

I'm using adminer to connect to my posgre, here is the code down below

registrasi.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <?php include 'connect.php';?>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
 //tampung value
if(isset($_POST['submitregis'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $agama = $_POST['agama'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $confirmpassword =$_POST['confirmpassword'];
  $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
  $kota = $_POST['kota'];
  $negara = $_POST['negara'];
  $kodepos =$_POST['kodepos'];

  //konfirmasi password
  if($password != $confirmpassword){
    //redirect
    header('location: registrasi.php?konfirmasipassword-failed');
  }else{
    //insert
    $insert=<<<EOF
INSERT INTO akun("nama", "email", "password", "jenis_kelamin", "agama", "alamat", "kota", "negara", "kode_pos")
VALUES ($name, $email,$gender,$agama,$password,$alamat,$kota,$negara,$kodepos);

EOF;
/*$insert=<<<EOF
INSERT INTO akun SET nama=$name, email="$email", 
password="$password", jenis_kelamin="$gender", 
agama="$agama",alamat="$alamat", kota="$kota", 
negara="$negara", kode_pos="$kodepos";


EOF;*/
    pg_query($db_handle, $insert);
    header('location:  registrasi.php');
  }

}

/*
if(isset($_POST['submitregis'])) {

  $name = $_POST['nama'];
  $email = $_POST['password'];
  $gender = $_POST['gender'];
  $agama = $_POST['agama'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $alamat = $_POST['alamat'];
  $kota = $_POST['kota'];
  $negara = $_POST['negara'];
  $kodepos = $_POST['kodepos'];

  $query = pg_query($db_handle, "INSERT INTO akun (nama,email,password,jenis_kelamin,
  agama,alamat,kota,negara,kode_pos) VALUES ('$name','$email','$gender','$agama',
  '$password','$alamat', '$kota', '$negara', '$kodepos');");
  if ( $query ) {
      echo  "Record Successfully Updated!";
  }

  else{
    echo "Failed";
  }

}

/*function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}*/

?>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
       <img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" style="height : 100px; width:100px;">
  </a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Daftar Kursus
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="daftar_kursus.php">Cooking</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IT dan Software</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Design</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Memahat</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">IT dan Software</a>
      </div>
       <!-- Dropdown -->
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Login/Sign Up
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="Login.php">Login</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="registrasi.php">Sign Up</a>
      </div>
    </ul>
      <form class="form-inline ml-auto">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  </div>
</nav> 

   <div class="card card bg-light text-dark" >
       <div class="card-body">
        <center> <h1>Register Yourself Here</h1> </center>
        <p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputName">Nama</label>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
<input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="inputEmail4">Email</label>
<span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
<input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
</div>
  </div>
  <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $passwordErr;?></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" onmouseover="this.type='text'"
       onmouseout="this.type='password'" placeholder="Password" name="password" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <small id="passwordHelpBlock" class="form-text text-muted">
  Your password must be 8-20 characters long, contain letters and numbers, and must not contain spaces, special characters, or emoji.
</small>
<label for="inputPassword">Confirm Password</label>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $confirmpasswordErr;?></span>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" onmouseover="this.type='text'"
       onmouseout="this.type='password'" placeholder="Password" name="confirmpassword" value="<?php echo $confirmpassword;?>">
<div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputState">Jenis Kelamin</label>
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="gender">
        <option>Perempuan</option>
        <option>Laki-Laki</option>
        <option>Prefer Not To Say</option>
      </select>
    </div>
       <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputState">Agama</label>
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $agamaErr;?></span>
      <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="agama">
        <option>Islam</option>
        <option>Protestan</option>
        <option>Katolik</option>
        <option>Hindu</option>
        <option>Budha</option>
        <option>Khonghucu</option>
        <option>Prefer Not To Say</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputAddress">Alamat</label>
    <span class="error">* <?php echo $alamatErr;?></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress" placeholder="Alamat" name="alamat">
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
      <label for="inputCity">Kota</label>
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $kotaErr;?></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Kota" name="kota">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="inputCountry">Negara</label>
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $negaraErr;?></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="negara" placeholder="Negara" name="negara">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3" >
      <label for="inputZip">Kode Pos</label>
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $kodeposErr;?></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="kodepos">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submitregis" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<?php
/*echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $password;
echo "<br>";
echo $gender;
echo "<br>";
echo $agama;
echo "<br>";
echo $alamat;
echo "<br>";
echo $kota;
echo "<br>";
echo $negara;
echo "<br>";
echo $kodepos;
echo "<br>";
*/
?>
       </div>
</div>


<div class="footer">
  <p>Created By GDMZ 2020</p>
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

I have tested the server connection and its all good, I can select data as well but I can't insert any data to my postgres so that is strange.

Comment: First the Postgres website documentation is for Postgres not PHP and Web development. Second and more to the point I can't see where you commit the transaction. This means the INSERT will only last for the session and will not be persisted to the database. I would also tail the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting the database.

Comment: I am trying to but sadly I cant access the log, I have no permission for it, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you install Postgres or are you querying someone else's install? What error do you get when you try to access it?

Comment: Im using adminer and yes im using some else's server, 
the error says that access denied